# Stop rotation in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I have a gif opened in After Effects. I typed w to allow me to rotate the gif. But, now I cannot drag the gif up or down. It just continues to rotate. How do I stop the rotation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cursor tool using the V key, or by pressing the icon on the toolbar.

[image]

Then when you select your object, you will be able to drag it around.

I highly recommend watching the first few videos here, as a beginners guide:

https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

It's old, but it's a great overview.